# Mongo DB not storing DateTime properly

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime, mongodb-.net-driver

The code is self explanatory. When I retrive object from DB its `DateTime` is different than the one I inserted. I would like to know how to fix it.

```
class MyClass
{
    public ObjectId _id;
    public DateTime date;
}

MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
MongoServer server = client.GetServer();

MyClass tmp = new MyClass();
tmp.date = DateTime.Now;

Console.WriteLine(tmp.date); // 11.7. 21:38:18

var coll = server.GetDatabase("test").GetCollection("test");
coll.Insert(tmp);

tmp = server.GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<MyClass>("test").FindOne();

Console.WriteLine(tmp.date); // 11.7. 19:34:46
```

Comment: Are you in the CET time zone? It seems the date is converted to UTC

Comment: Im in CEST but even if its caused by it I still dont know how to fix it.

Comment: That should be easy to google.

Comment: Have you tried setting [DateTime.Kind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind(v=vs.110).aspx) to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Setting `DateTime.Kind` helped. Thanks

Comment: We found that Mongo stores times as UTC, even if we save it as ET. And that's not a bad thing. It's usually not a good idea to store local times. One option is to just work with UTC in the DB. If you need to convert it to some other time in a UI, then go ahead, but UTC in the DB is a good thing.